# Jquery addClass not working on mobile browser

Tags: jquery, mobile, browser

I have a simple addClass functionality on button click. It works fine on normal browser but

```
$('#filter_button').click(function(){
         $('.contextual-links-region .panel-2col > .panel-col-first').addClass("show_left_filters");         
         $('#mini-panel-top_lists > .panel-col-first').css({"display":"none"});
         $('#mini-panel-top_lists > .panel-2col .panel-col-first').removeClass("show_left_filters");
         $('#mini-panel-content_top').hide();        
         return false;      
});
```

Can someone please guide me about it.

Best Regards,

Comment: "fine on normal browser but" - ?

Comment: do you have media queries in your css?

Comment: @Nicolas78 Read the title - doesn't work on mobile browser.  rafiq - can you tell us which mobile browser, and have you tried it on other mobile browsers?

Comment: @Archer yes I was hoping that the missing fragment would include more specific information

Comment: Yes, I am using Media queries in CSS. I am testing it on iphone 4s Chrome

Comment: I have the same issue... `addClass` does not class in Chrome running on mobile. Works fine on desktop.